# Facing issue saving subdocument in mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am new in nodejs, express and MongoDB. I am creating rest APIs where I have to add the form. The form is getting the family data so I try to use a sub-document for father and mother details but cannot add these details in DB.

**MODEL**

```
const fatherSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        fatherName:{
            type:String,
            require:true,
        },
        fatherProfession:{
            type:String,
            require:true,
        },
        fatherImage:{
            type:String,
            require:true,
        }   
    }
)

const motherSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        motherName:{
            type:String,
            require:true,
        },
        motherProfession:{
            type:String,
            require:true,
        },
        motherImage:{
            type:String,
            require:true,
        }   
    }
)

const familyDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        language:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        father:fatherSchema,  
        mother:motherSchema,
        details:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Number
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: Number,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps:true,
    }
)
```

In my route I try to add the details in form in this way

```
        // ADD INTO FORM
        let form = new FamilyDetails(_.pick(req.body,['language','details','user_id']))
        form.father.fatherName = req.body.fatherName
        // form.father.fatherProfession = req.body.fatherProfession
        // form.father.fatherImage = fatherPic
        // form.mother.motherImage = motherPic
        // form.mother.motherName = req.body.motherName
        // form.mother.motherProfession = req.body.motherProfession
```

but I'm getting err on this line

> form.father.fatherName = req.body.fatherName

The ERR is this : ** "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'fatherName') **

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you need father and mother schema be separate? Have you tried having them inside the family schema?

Another option could be mother and father schema to be a document such as user document you referenced on the family schema

Comment: Hi, Padawan, yes I try it in family schema it's now working.

Comment: something like this in family schema:  father:{ fatherName:String, fatherProfessoin:String, fatherImage:String }